# Access x64 TEB C++ & Assembly

Tags: windows, assembly, visual-c++, x86-64, kernel32

In 32-bit assembly, I can access the `ProcessEnvironmentBlock` of the `TEB` structure. From there I access `Ldr` of the `TEB` structure.

This technique is described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block

The code to do this in 32-bit assembly is:

```
void* ptr = NULL;

__asm
{
    mov eax, FS:[0x18]
    mov eax, [eax + 0x30]  //Offset of PEB
    mov eax, [eax + 0x0C]  //Offset of LDR in PEB structure
    mov eax, _ptr
};

std::cout<<ptr<<"\n";
```

The TEB structure can be seen here: http://msdn.moonsols.com/win7rtm_x64/TEB.html
and the PEB structure can be seen here: http://msdn.moonsols.com/win7rtm_x64/PEB.html

The above works for 32-bit code.

However, I want to also write code to work on x64 machines. I viewed the x64 version of the structures and wrote:

```
__asm
{
    mov rax, GS:[0x30]
    mov rax, [rax + 0x60]
    mov rax, [rax + 0x18]
    mov rax, _ptr
};
```

This can be done using `Winnt.h` `NtCurrentTeb()` but I want to use assembly.

However, it fails to work at all. Any ideas why?

Comment: Did you trace into `NtCurrentTeb` and check the offsets to make sure they are actually correct?

Comment: Fail meaning `_ptr` has a different value from `NTCurrentTeb`. I will trace it and check again. I am fairly certain I did get them right.

Comment: Do you read TEB from 64bit process or 32bit process (WOW)?

Comment: x64. I figured out what is wrong. It's my syntax. The same code works just fine if I use AT&T syntax but NOT intel syntax. So I must be doing something wrong for sure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21974224/convert-att-syntax-to-intel-syntax-asm

Comment: `mov rax, _ptr` moves the value of `_ptr` into `rax` not the other way around. If that's your actual code `_ptr` should still hold a null pointer value.

Comment: Ah! That fixed it! :D  If you put that as an answer, I'll mark it solved.

Comment: http://msdn.moonsols.com is down, you can use https://www.vergiliusproject.com for browsing Windows NT kernel structures.

Answer (score 4):

If you using visual studio, you can use Intrinsics!

[x86]
__readfsbyte
__readfsdword
__readfsqword
__readfsword

[x64]
__readgsbyte
__readgsdword
__readgsqword
__readgsword

Good luck~

Answer (score 1):

Visual studio doesn't allow inline assembler for X64 C++.  The __asm keyword isn't supported.  You can write your assembler in a separate file and link it in or you can use intrinsics do what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this, you must create an .asm file in Visual Studio like described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/masm-for-x64-ml64-exe?view=vs-2019).

To access the TEB/PEB in x64 compiled with Visual Studio you can use the following code:

```
GetTEBAsm64 proc
    push rbx
    xor rbx,rbx
    xor rax,rax
    mov rbx, qword ptr gs:[00000030h]
    mov rax, rbx
    pop rbx
    ret
GetTEBAsm64 endp

GetPEBAsm64 proc
    push rbx
    xor rbx,rbx
    xor rax,rax
    mov rbx, qword ptr gs:[00000060h]
    mov rax, rbx
    pop rbx
    ret
GetPEBAsm64 endp
```

And then simply use them:

```
PTEB pTeb = GetTEBAsm64();
PPEB pPeb = GetPEBAsm64();
```

**PRO TIP:**

You can define your own "versions" of these structs (PTEB/PPEB), to include more or less information in them.