# Convert AT&T syntax to Intel Syntax (ASM)

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

I've been trying to access the peb information of an executable as seen here: [Access x64 TEB C++ & Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21973330/access-x64-teb-c-assembly?noredirect=1#comment33297329_21973330)

The code works only in AT&T syntax for some odd reason but when I try to use Intel syntax, it fails to give the same value. There's of course an error on my part. So I'm asking..

How can I convert:

```
int main()
{
    void* ptr = 0; //0x7fff5c4ff3c0
    asm volatile
    (
        "movq %%gs:0x30, %%rax\n\t"
        "movq 0x60(%%rax), %%rax\n\t"
        "movq 0x18(%%rax), %%rax\n\t"
        "movq %%rax, %0\n"
        : "=r" (ptr) ::
    );
}
```

to Intel Syntax?

I tried:

```
asm volatile
(
    "movq rax, gs:[0x30]\n\t"
    "movq rax, [rax + 0x60]\n\t"
    "movq rax, [rax + 0x18]\n\t"
    "movq rax, %0\n"
    : "=r" (ptr) ::
);
```

and:

```
asm volatile
(
    "mov rax, QWORD PTR gs:[0x30]\n\t"
    "mov rax, QWORD PTR [rax + 0x60]\n\t"
    "mov rax, QWORD PTR [rax + 0x18]\n\t"
    "movq rax, %0\n"                     //mov rax, QWORD PTR [%0]\n
    : "=r" (ptr) ::
);
```

They do not print the same value as the AT&T syntax: `0x7fff5c4ff3c0`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to reverse operand order on the last line. That said, the only instruction you need to have in asm is the first one due to the `gs` segment override, the rest could be done in C.

Comment: That solved it but, why only the first instruction? I will mark this answer as solved when it lets me.

Comment: @Cant Because the remaining instructions simply perform pointer arithmetics and dereferencing. Nothing you cannot do in C.

Comment: Also note that you forgot to tell the compiler that you clobber `rax`.